# Reducing lookup time in collections

Tags: list, vector, language-agnostic, lookup

I've often heard that one of the major benefits of using a Vector over a List, is that the lookup time is `O(1)` for vectors, but a worst case of `O(n)` for lists, because if the queried item is at the back of the list, you'd need to go through its entirety.

So my question is; how can the vector, a collection like the list, have a "flat" lookup time? What trick is used to achieve this? I'm referring to any language where this is the case, not just C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, Vectors feature the performance of regular Arrays due to them being simply Dynamic Arrays. Their memory structure is a contiguous set of storage, like an array, but with extra capacity for growth. If you know the specific index the data is located at, you can simply access data at that location. This is done by calculating a memory offset to that location. If you don't know what data you're looking for, however, you'll still need to iterate over them to find the index within the Vector.

Lists, most commonly implemented as doubly-linked lists are simply storage locations that contain a pointer to the previous/next location. In order to find a specific location you'll need to iterate over all of them at worst. You can, in theory, "cache" the pointer location of a specific value but there's no guarantee it'll be there again which is why you iterate every time.

Because of these properties though, you can however insert very quickly into the middle of a list but not so quickly into a Vector because all data needs to be moved over to make room.

For more info, I'd recommend taking a read through the [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) and [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) documentation, as well as the [wiki article on Dynamic Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) which includes a nice comparison of list data structures' performance.

Comment: so even though lists, arrays, and vectors alike all support accessing an element by index (in most languages); the performance is still an issue in this regard?

Comment: Yes, because in order to go to the nth record in a linked-list, you need to iterate over n items. For Arrays and Vectors, if you want to go to the nth record you simply mathematically calculate an offset from the base address.